# How do I remove values like \'a\' from an array with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am stuck at this challenge on codewars where I have to return only numbers from an array as a new array and neglect all non-numbers.

I was presented with something like this  ['1', '2', \'a\', \'b\'].
This is meant it return just [1, 2]

I tried this.

```
function filter_list(l) {
    return l.filter(c => c>=0 && c <= 999)
}
```

I got my `[1, 2]` in the case of this `['1', '2', \'a\', \'b\']` but got a `[\'1\']` in the case of `[\'1\']` instead of `[]`

What do I do?

Comment: is that an array ['1', '2', \'a\', \'b\'] ? its not a valid array probably . Let the community have a look. @Ezeoke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if the elements are actually numbers or if they are strings containing numbers. Here are a couple of solutions using filter:

```
function num (arr) {
  return arr.filter(c => Number.isInteger(c));
}

function num2 (arr) {
  return arr.filter(c => typeof c === 'number');
}
```

Check out these resources:

Number.isInteger()-
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger

typeof-
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Answer (score 0):

this should work ( if you pass an array without the backslashes like `[1,'2','a']` )

```
function filter_list(l) {
    return l.filter(c => parseInt(c) >=0 && parseInt(c) <= 999)
}
```